# Is there something like phpMyAdmin for Memcached?

Tags: memcached

Is there any tool to see the keys/values stored in my memcached instance?

I've found simple scripts like this http://snipt.org/xtP, but I get only the keys.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a project called [phpMemcacheAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/) on Google code. To be honest, I did not try it before.

You may already know that memcache protocol is a text-based protocol which means you can use `telnet` application to access memcached and issue the desired commands.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. I know about the telnet interface, but this tool provides the info in a nicer view :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: I am using this tool is really good